# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar integration with Outlook 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar, outlook-2010

I have created a calendar list and then in list settings I've added the column Attendees. Then I created an event with certain attendees and the type as meeting. And later integrated to outlook 2010 through the Connect to Outlook option in the ribbon button. I can view the created sharepoint calender along with the default outlook calendar in outlook. But when I select an event it doesn't show the attendees I have added through sharepoint.

Is there a way to show the attendees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no great way to expose custom SharePoint columns Outlook with the native connection. Outlook only understands a strict set of columns for appointment types.

We have been working on and Outlook add-in that extends the functionality and exposes any custom columns directly within Outlook 2007/2010. You can find more at http://propersync.com/unifiedcalendar.aspx.

*Disclaimer - I am part of the ProperSync team and hope this has been a relevant and useful posting.

Comment: As ProperSync is closed down I wondering is there any other solution, to exposes any custom columns directly within Outlook 2010?